# I want to create .exe file to create multiple folder at a same time

Tags: batch-file

I want to create .exe setup or batch file to create Multiple folders at same time.
and folder name prompt to give or take from .txt file.

Comment: ...and what's the question??

Answer (score 0):

Your question is Operating system dependent.

#### To create an executable

In windows you can use Visual Studio console application to create a c++ code and build it to obtain a .exe file. You have to take care on the linking options.
To create a directory simply do **mkdir("foldername")** and to read or write from txt file, create a file stream and use getline to read the names of folder.

In linux I suppose it can be done by writing a bash script.

Answer (score 0):

If you are ok to enter the name of the folder each time, you can simply use the `md` command of the Windows Command Line!

Syntax: `md MyFolderName`